# Android: datepickerdialog cancel dialog without getting the date

Tags: android, android-dialog, android-datepicker

In a fragment class I'm using this snippet:

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
                int mYear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
                int mMonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
                int mDay = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

                DatePickerDialog dialog = new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), datePickerListener, mYear, mMonth, mDay);
                dialog.setButton(DatePickerDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE, "OK", dialog);
                dialog.setButton(DatePickerDialog.BUTTON_NEGATIVE, "ANNULLA", (DialogInterface.OnClickListener)null);
                dialog.show();


private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener datePickerListener
            = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

        // when dialog box is closed, below method will be called.
        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int selectedYear,
                              int selectedMonth, int selectedDay) {
            //Do whatever you want
            Log.d("DATEPICKER","La data presa è "+selectedDay+selectedMonth+selectedYear);
        }
    };
```

Unfortunately, I'm getting the date on clicking both POSITIVE and NEGATIVE button. Of course, I need the date only with the positive button (but, I see entries in the Logs for both).

Comment: It seems like you create the DatePickerDialog "dialog" but you don't use it... try to replace DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener" with "dialog.OnDateSetListener".

Comment: Is there a reason you are calling `setButton()` to override the default buttons?  The dialog has two default buttons for Cancel and Set.  When the default buttons are used, only Set causes the `onDateSet()` method of the listener to be called.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the source code (tested on API 16) of *DatePickerDialog* you'll notice that *onDateSet()* is called always in *onStop()* method.
I overridden default positive button behaviour, and implemented positive button listener instead *onDateSet()*

```
private class ReportDatePickerDialog extends DialogFragment implements android.content.DialogInterface.OnClickListener {

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        DatePickerDialog dialog = new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), null, initialYear, initialMonth, initialDay);
        dialog.setCancelable(true);
        dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);
        dialog.setButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE, "Ok", ReportDatePickerDialog.this);
        return dialog;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        ((DatePickerDialog)getDialog()).onClick(dialog, which);

        if (which != DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE) {
            return;
        }
        DatePicker datePicker = ((DatePickerDialog)getDialog()).getDatePicker();
        datePicker.getDayOfMonth();
        datePicker.getMonth();
        datePicker.getYear();
    }
}
```

I guess eventually it's better off to create custom dialog window in cases like that.

Answer (score -1):

This is a link to Source code for new Android Lollipop Calendar app

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Calendar.git/+archive/android-5.1.0_r3.tar.gz

You may have to add the following dependencies as well.

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/ex/

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/opt/colorpicker/

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/opt/calendar/

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/opt/datetimepicker/

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/opt/timezonepicker/

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Calendar.git/+/android-5.1.0_r3

You can clone the repos . for example git clone https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/ex . But what I am afraid is that you may need other dependencies for that as well. However, you gotta try first.

Comment: final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
mYear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
mMonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
mDay = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
 
DatePickerDialog dailog= new DatePickerDialog(getActivity,
        new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
 
            @Override
            public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year,
                    int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
                txtDate.setText(dayOfMonth + "-"
                        + (monthOfYear + 1) + "-" + year);
 
            }
        }, mYear, mMonth, mDay);
dailog.show();

Comment: sorry.. this code worked for me.. sorry for the inconvenience